# How to set Retrofit response body data in Listview

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

In **Daata** function try to fetch data from server. Successfully fetched, but data cant be set in ArrayList

```
List<FlowerListModel>flowerListModels=new ArrayList<>();
```

Cause i want to set **flowerListModels** data in  **FlowerAdapter** and show in listview

```
  public void Daata() {
    Call<List<FlowerListData>>listCall=apiInterface.getflowers();
    listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<FlowerListData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FlowerListData>> call, Response<List<FlowerListData>> response) {
            Log.d("DataCheck",new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
            List<FlowerListModel>flowerListModels=new ArrayList<>();

          FlowerAdapter flowerAdapter = new FlowerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flowerListModels);
            listView.setAdapter(flowerAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FlowerListData>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is **FlowerListModel** class

```
package bdservers.com.schoolmanagement.Model;

public class FlowerListModel {

    private String category;
    private String instructions;
    private String photo;
    private String name;
    private String price;

    public FlowerListModel(){}
    public FlowerListModel(String category, String instructions, String photo, String name,String price){
        this.category=category;
        this.instructions=instructions;
        this.photo=photo;
        this.name=name;
       this.price=price;
       }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }

    public void setInstructions(String instructions) {
        this.instructions = instructions;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Comment: try this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: what you mean by  'cant be set in ArrayList '

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the response data you get. You'll need to populate your newly created array list (flowerListModels) with the entries from the data you get as a response. Otherwise you are just trying to display an empty array.

Comment: Your response List is FlowerListData but you set adapter with FlowerListModel. Change Retrofit API Interface method change return type to FlowerListModel if your response is FlowerListModel means. After in your adapter FlowerAdapter flowerAdapter = new FlowerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),response.body());
            listView.setAdapter(flowerAdapter);

Comment: thank u so much .. yes my fault was   in response ... thanx again .solved

Answer (score 1):

You are setting empty `ArrayList` to your adapter, I have highlighted the line where you have made the error, and also the correct line that you need

```
public void Daata() {
Call<List<FlowerListData>>listCall=apiInterface.getflowers();
listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<FlowerListData>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<FlowerListData>> call, Response<List<FlowerListData>> response) {
        Log.d("DataCheck",new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

        /**
        * You are setting this empty list to adapter
        *List<FlowerListModel>flowerListModels=new ArrayList<>();
        */

        List<FlowerListModel> flowerListModels = new ArrayList<>();
        flowerListModels = response.body();

      FlowerAdapter flowerAdapter = new FlowerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flowerListModels);
        listView.setAdapter(flowerAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<FlowerListData>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: in FlowerAdapter cannot be applied
to
(Context,
java.util.List<bdservers.com.schoolmanagement.Retrofit.Response.FlowerListData>)
 showing this error

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new empty `List` here: `List<FlowerListModel>flowerListModels=new ArrayList<>();`

You can try something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<FlowerListData>> call, Response<List<FlowerListData>> response) {
        Log.d("DataCheck",new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
        FlowerAdapter flowerAdapter = new FlowerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),response.body());
        listView.setAdapter(flowerAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: in FlowerAdapter cannot be applied to (Context, java.util.List<bdservers.com.schoolmanagement.Retrofit.Respo‌​nse.FlowerListData>) showing this error

Answer (score 0):

Create BaseResponse model like this

```
public class BaseResponse {

    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Object> alObjects;

    public BaseResponse(List<Object> alObjects) {
        this.alObjects = alObjects;
    }

    public List<Object> getAlObjects() {
        return alObjects;
    }

    public void setAlObjects(List<Object> alObjects) {
        this.alObjects = alObjects;
    }

}
```

Then get data from server

```
@POST(Constants.URL_API_DATA)
BaseResponse executeBaseResponse(@Body String mData);
```

Cheers!!